# How to pass data from one component to another in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-context

For all React Gurus! The logic is that I make a query to overpass and get some GeoJSON, now I need to pass this GeoJSON object to another Component (which is not its child) so that there I could make some calculations and show it on the screen.
The general structure is like this: There is a Main.js component which has two children MapBox.js and CalculationResults.js. MapBox.js has a child OverpassLayer.js which gives me GeoJSON. This GeoJSON I need to pass to CalculationResults.js. I tried to implement callback function all the way from parent Main.js but it always returns me the GeoJSON from the previous query. Could you please help me with the correct way of passing data between Components.
This is my OverpassLayer.js

```js
const OverpassLayer = (props) => {
  const [geojson, setGeojson] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    makeQuery();
  }, [props.street, props.houseNumber]);

  const makeQuery = () => {
    const query = `[out:json];nwr["addr:street"="${props.street}"]["addr:housenumber"="${props.houseNumber}"][building](59.3518076,24.55017,59.5915769,24.9262831);out geom;`;

    const options = {
      flatProperties: true,
      overpassUrl: "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter",
    };
    overpass(query, dataHandler, options);
  };

  const dataHandler = (error, osmData) => {
    if (
      !error &&
      osmData.features !== undefined &&
      osmData.features[0] !== undefined
    ) {
      console.log(osmData.features[0]);
      let area = (getArea(osmData.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0]));
      console.log(area);
      setGeojson(osmData);
    }
  };

  function keyFunction(geojson) {
    if (geojson.features.length === 0) {
      return "";
    } else {
      return geojson.features[0].id;
    }
  }

  function getArea(array) {
    if (array) {
      let arrayPolygon = array;
      let polygon = turf.polygon([arrayPolygon]);
      let area = turf.area(polygon);
      return area;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  return geojson ? <GeoJSON key={keyFunction(geojson)} data={geojson} /> : null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to store the data in `localStorage`. For the example, below `setGeojson(osmData)` you can write  `localStorage.setItem("Geojson", JSON.stringify(Geojson));` and in `CalculationResults.js` you can call it in `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount()`:

```
const getGeojson = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Geojson"));
if(getGeojson){
    if(getGeojson.length > 0){
        setGeojson(getGeojson);
    }
}
```

the more advanced way is to use redux

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! It works, but not as expected. Basically, it gives me a result of a previous search. For example, first time I type some address - doesn't give the json, second time make search - gives the geojson of a previous search, third time make search - gives the geojson of a second search.

Comment: If you are using useEffect try to listen to the localstorage change, for the example: `useEffect((...), [getGeojson])`